# How to use redux saga with infinite scroll on Flatlist?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-saga, react-native-flatlist

I'm developing my first React Native app and it is the first time I'm using redux and redux saga. So I've built a Flatlist to have infinite scroll with a API endpoint tha returns posts (10 per page). But I don't know how to use the reducers to return the posts, control the loading indicator and keep track of the page number in the store, using redux saga.

My code is the following:

Home.js

```
this.state = {
    page: 1,
    totalPages: 10,
    loading: false,
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.loadMorePosts();
}

loadMorePosts = () => {
    this.setState(() => { loading: true });
    this.setState(() => { page: this.state.page++ });
    this.props.loadPosts(this.state.page);
}

<AnimatedFlatList
    ...
    onEndReached={this.loadMorePosts}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
/>

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.posts,
});
```

Posts Action

```
export function loadPosts(page){
    return {
        type: Types.FETCH_POSTS,
        payload: { page }
    };
}
```

Posts saga

```
export function* fetchPosts(action) {
    const response = yield call(api.get, `/posts/${action.payload.page}`);
    yield put({ type: Types.LOAD_POSTS, payload: { posts: response.data } });
}
```

Posts Reducer

```
export default function posts(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case Types.LOAD_POSTS:
            return [ ...state, ...action.payload.posts ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

With this I can fetch the posts and load into the Flatlist, but if I change screens I lose track of the actual page number, that will be set to 0 again in the Home.js constructor. And there is no visual feedback since the loading state is not defined with the mapStateToProps function...

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest have the page number and the loading indicator within a redux reducer state also.

Comment: You mean create new separate reducers that will listen for the same event after the saga fetches the posts?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on a comment: (Not tested code but principle is there).

Saga

```
export function* fetchPosts(action) {
    try {
        yield put({ type: Types.LOAD_POSTS_START, payload: { page: action.payload.page } });
        const response = yield call(api.get, `/posts/${action.payload.page}`);
        yield put({ type: Types.LOAD_POSTS, payload: { posts: response.data } });
    }
    catch {
        //perhaps roll back page count?
        yield put({ type: Types.LOAD_POSTS_END, payload: { } });
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
   isLoading: false,
   currentPage: 0,
   posts: []
}
export default function posts(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case Types.LOAD_POSTS_START: 
            return {
                ...state, 
                currentPage: action.payload.page,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case Types.LOAD_POSTS_END: 
            return {
                ...state, 
                isLoading: false
            };
        case Types.LOAD_POSTS:
            return {
              ...state, 
              isLoading: false,
              posts: [ ...state.posts, ...action.payload.posts ]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then in your component connect to this state rather than have it stored in the components state object

Comment: How to empty posts?

Answer (score 0):

Make a saga/task that just does a `fetch` and returns a promise like this:

```
const fetchAction = (input, init) => {
  let resolve;
  const promise = new Promise(resolveArg => resolve = resolveArg)
  return { type:'FETCH_ACTION', input, init, promise, resolve }
}

function fetchActionWorker({ input, init, resolve}) {
   const res = yield call(fetch, input, init);
   resolve(res);
}

function* fetchActionWatcher() {
   yield takeEvery('FETCH_ACTION', fetchWorker);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
class List extends Component {
    render() {
       return <Button title="fetch" onPress={this.doFetch} />
    }
    doFetch = async () => {
        const res = await dispatch(fetchAction('url', { method:'GET' })).promise;
    }
}
```

Calling the `fetch` action gives you a promise right away.